# How to edit an ABAP project of "program" object category when I receive the message that its "package is missing"?

Tags: abap, editing, abap-adt

I have an ABAP program in a SAP system which I bring in via a transaction code. I need to make change to it. I found out the source code in the development environment. When I try to edit it, it is saying:

> ZIS package is missing.

How to correctly edit it?

When I am trying to edit it, it is saying some package are missing.

Answer (score 1):

What this typically means is that you imported it in some way without the original package named "ZIS". I don't know of a workaround other then first create the missing package  and then you'll be able to edit the source.